# Variables in where-clause

Tags: database, variables, typo3, where-clause, typoscript

I am on my first Typo3 project. I stuck on an effort now for several days. I searched here and googeled. But it seems, that my question is that simple, so that no one asks it :-)

I have a FLUIDTEMPLATE in my setup.typoscript (which came from sitepackagebuilder.com). Everything works, and also the websites looks like i wanted to.

BUT: I have to join a where-clause with variables. This is my Code:

```
page = PAGE
page {

    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {

        variables {
            
            dayNow = USER
            dayNow.userFunc = VereinLilaWinkel\LilaWinkelTemplate\Schultermine->dayNow

            day30 = USER
            day30.userFunc = VereinLilaWinkel\LilaWinkelTemplate\Schultermine->day30
        }

        dataProcessing {

            60 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
            60 {

                table = tx_mask_termin
                pidInList = 123
                selectFields = tx_mask_termin.*, usr_plz.plz, usr_plz.ort
                leftjoin = usr_plz ON usr_plz.uid = tx_mask_termin.tx_mask_plzort
                where = tx_mask_termin.tx_mask_datum BETWEEN {dateNow} AND {date30}
                orderBy = tx_mask_termin.tx_mask_datum ASC
                as = nextSchultermine
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The userFuncs work fine, i get back for example (today):

- dateNow: 2023-05-02
- date30: 2023-06-01

The goal is to get the where-statement working. As far, i can only hard-code it every day. So i know, that the rest of the query works fine.

I tried all kinds of wrap and dataWrap that i could find. I tried lib.myValues, or as constants... I also asked ChatGPT for it... No running version yet... The variables wont get rendered inside the where-clause!

Comment: The defined variables are available in the fluid template. Create a new data processor by extending the DatabaseQueryProcessor and there you can query the database as you like.

Comment: Thanks Hatzegopteryx! Unfortunately i don't understand your idea. Would you mind posting this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both, the `variables` and the `DataProcessor` are defined on the same level and there is no nested `dataProcessing` your apporach has to fail.

The reason is, that the variables are not available at the time the dataProcessing is going to happen, so you can't access them as data for the TypoScript of the DataProcessor.

You could still achieve what you want with TypoScript though, since there are several date functions available via `stdWrap`.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html?highlight=strtotime#strtotime

```
60 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
60 {
    table = tx_mask_termin
    pidInList = 123
    selectFields = tx_mask_termin.*, usr_plz.plz, usr_plz.ort
    leftjoin = usr_plz ON usr_plz.uid = tx_mask_termin.tx_mask_plzort
    where.cObject = COA
    where.cObject {
       10 = TEXT
       10.value = now
       10.strtotime = 1
       10.noTrimWrap = |tx_mask_termin.tx_mask_datum BETWEEN | AND                    
       20 = TEXT
       20.value = +30 day
       20.strtotime = 1
    }
    orderBy = tx_mask_termin.tx_mask_datum ASC
    as = nextSchultermine
}
```

But as mentioned in the comment for Sivas solution, I would recommend a custom DataProcessor instead.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Jo Hasenau!

You're my man! Thanks for describing the problem and the hints to stdWrap date-functions. For the tx_mask_datum column is really a DATE and not a TSTAMP, i could achieve this like that:

```
60 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
60 {

    table = tx_mask_termin
    pidInList = 123
    selectFields = tx_mask_termin.*, usr_plz.plz, usr_plz.ort
    leftjoin = usr_plz ON usr_plz.uid = tx_mask_termin.tx_mask_plzort
    where.cObject = COA
    where.cObject {
        10 = TEXT
        10.value = now
        10.field = tstamp
        10.date = Y-m-d
        10.noTrimWrap = |tx_mask_termin.tx_mask_datum BETWEEN "|" AND
        20 = TEXT
        20 {
            strtotime = +30 day
            strftime = %Y-%m-%d
        }
        20.noTrimWrap = | "|"
    }
    orderBy = tx_mask_termin.tx_mask_datum ASC
    as = nextSchultermine
}
```

For me as a PHP-developer it is often not clearly in the world of typo3.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can manage this without the use of Userfunction. For instance, you can use the below code to get the first day of next month
using the following code

```
DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

to get the current date, you can use the following code

`DAY(CURDATE()) AS current_day;`

```
  table = tx_mask_termin
                pidInList = 123
                selectFields = tx_mask_termin.*, usr_plz.plz, usr_plz.ort
                leftjoin = usr_plz ON usr_plz.uid = tx_mask_termin.tx_mask_plzort
                where = tx_mask_termin.tx_mask_datum BETWEEN DAY(CURDATE()) AND DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                orderBy = tx_mask_termin.tx_mask_datum ASC
                as = nextSchultermine
```

maybe you would try like this. Or you can write your own custom **DataProcessor**

For instance, I tried this in my local

```
150 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
150 {

            table = pages
            pidInList = 62
            selectFields = pages.*, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(crdate), '%Y-%m-%d') as crdate, CURDATE() AS current_day
            where = DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(crdate), '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
            orderBy = pages.crdate ASC
            as = nextSchultermine
        }
```

The above code would return, all pages created between `today` and `2023-06-01`. Hope you can extend this code snippet and implement your requirement.

[image]

Comment: If this is going to be a public extension that should/could be used by others, I would definitely recommend to go for a custom DataProcessor, because you could create the query with Doctrine then, making it run on several different DB systems.

Comment: Hi Siva! Thanks, this sounds so logical. But unfortunately it isn't rendered. It results in: "... datum BETWEEN DAY(CURDATE()) AND DAY(CURDATE()) ... ". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: IMHO the MySQL functions have to fail anyway, since DAY would return a value between 1 and 31 and I guess tx_mask_datum is a tstamp, isn't it?

Comment: @user3395986 As #Jo Hasenau mentioned, the mentioned code would fail as DAY returns a value between 1 and 31.  This was just an example, never the less I updated my answer a bit. Hope that will help :)